# Unable to parse URDF using command line but can do it in launch file

Tags: ros, ros2, xacro, robot-description, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am beginning to learn ROS and have encountered a strange issue. I have created 2 packages called, my_first_cpp_pkg and urdf_example, which contain xacro xmls of their own for URDF creation. I am getting to know the functionality of the launch file for ease.

I have an xacro file called example_urdf.robot.xacro in the package urdf_example, which if I try to run via command line to create the robot_description topic

```
ros2 run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher --ros-args -p robot_description:="$(xacro ros_articubot_tutorial/urdf_example/description/example_robot.urdf.xacro)"
```

throws the following error:-

```
[rcutils|error_handling.c:65] an error string (message, file name, or formatted message) will be truncated
[ERROR] [1659504478.236363109] [rcl]: Failed to parse global arguments
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLInvalidROSArgsError'

      what():  failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '-p robot_description:=<?xml version="1.0" ?
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from ros_articubot_tutorial/urdf_example/description/example_robot.urdf.xacro | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="robot">
  <!-- This is an example of a URDF. -->
  <!-- As we move through the file, new things to note will be pointed out. -->
  <!-- It's not meant an example of GOOD design, but an example of some of the various features of URDF/xacro. -->
  <!-- Thi, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.13/src/rcl/arguments.c:325
```

However, if I run via a launch file, it works properly-

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

# Specify the name of the package and path to xacro file within the package
pkg_name = 'urdf_example'
file_subpath = 'description/example_robot.urdf.xacro'

# Use xacro to process the file
xacro_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),file_subpath)
robot_description_raw = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()

# Configure the node
node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description_raw}] # add other parameters here if required
)


# Run the node
return LaunchDescription([
    node_robot_state_publisher
])
```

I wanted to see if it's the issue while processing of *xacro* file, so I manually parsed it and it works. Then I wanted to test if it's the issue with the command, then I tested the same robot_state_publisher command but gave the path of urdf of the package my_first_cpp_pkg/urdf_path and it works.

So, if it's neither an issue with xml parsing nor an issue with command, then I am not able to identify what is the additional information provided by launch file which makes it work without throwing any error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404549/unable-to-parse-urdf-using-command-line-but-can-do-it-in-launch-file./) by [manish.nayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29139/manish.nayak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue thread seems to be connected to this problem (but it is already solved, implemented and merged...):

- https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/119

and

- https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/126

I think this can hint us the place of the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLInvalidROSArgsError'

      what():  failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '-p robot_description:=<?xml version="1.0" ?
```

Why isn't it a string, but just a file-as-it-is?

In your launchfile you have two steps there:

`robot_description_raw = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()`

1. process file, then
2. convert it to XML

Maybe that is the difference?

Overall, in the terminal I would use only the path to the URDF file, [like here](https://industrial-training-dev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/session3/ros2/0-Intro-to-URDF.html):

```
ros2 run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher urdf/my_robot.urdf
```

And lauchfiles otherwise, for URDF / XACRO URDF, [e.g. from the next section of ROS Industrial](https://industrial-training-dev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/session3/ros2/1-Workcell-XACRO.html).

---

I found your example there: https://articulatedrobotics.xyz/ready-for-ros-7-urdf/ and use `check_urdf` (from `sudo apt install liburdfdom-tools`) to check it and got these errors:

```
$ check_urdf Desktop/example_robot.urdf.xacro 
Warning: link 'slider_link' material 'blue' undefined.
         at line 84 in /build/urdfdom-VnCcob/urdfdom-1.0.4+ds/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Warning: link 'slider_link' material 'blue' undefined.
         at line 84 in /build/urdfdom-VnCcob/urdfdom-1.0.4+ds/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error:   Unable to parse component [${arm_length/2}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
         at line 102 in /build/urdfdom-VnCcob/urdfdom-1.0.4+ds/urdf_parser/src/pose.cpp
Error:   Could not parse visual element for Link [arm_link]
         at line 453 in /build/urdfdom-VnCcob/urdfdom-1.0.4+ds/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
Error:   Unable to parse component [${pi/2}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
         at line 114
```

But, after saving in the same folder these three files from there: https://github.com/joshnewans/urdf_example/tree/main/description I could use xacro to get normal URDF from XACROURDF, it was parsed correctly too

```
ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~/Desktop$ xacro example_robot.urdf.xacro > test_robot.urdf
ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~/Desktop$ check_urdf test_robot.urdf 
robot name is: robot
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
root Link: world has 1 child(ren)
    child(1):  base_link
        child(1):  slider_link
            child(1):  arm_link
                child(1):  camera_link
                    child(1):  camera_link_optical
```

The different behavior in the terminal is surprising for sure.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manish.nayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29139/manish.nayak/) on 2022-08-03**:
I see. It indeed seems like a very old issue which has been fixed and even I believe that step 2 which converts to XML does the trick. What I don't understand is that I have been following the [tutorials](https://articulatedrobotics.xyz/ready-for-ros-6-tf/) where they do the same. Also, this is the command and output where the exact same input works, albeit for a different urdf:-

```
   ros2 run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher --ros-args -p robot_description:="$(xacro ros_articubot_tutorial/my_first_cpp_pkg/urdf/example_robot.urdf)" 
    Parsing robot urdf xml string.
    Link base had 1 children
    Link l3 had 1 children
    Link l2 had 1 children
    Link l1 had 1 children
    Link grip had 0 children
    Link camera had 0 children
    [INFO] [1659520565.730462926] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base .....
```

Does the content of the URDF cause some difference?

**Comment by [manish.nayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29139/manish.nayak/) on 2022-08-04**:
*The different behavior in the terminal is surprising for sure.*

Exactly! But I guess I would stick with this approach for now, although the root cause is still not clear. Thanks.

```
Overall, in the terminal I would use only the path to the URDF file, like here:

ros2 run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher urdf/my_robot.urdf

And lauchfiles otherwise, for URDF / XACRO URDF, e.g. from the next section of ROS Industrial.
```